# C++ When checking for equality between a variable and 0, gives segment fault (when debugging)

Tags: c++

let's say i have an array like this:

```
1 0 0 
0 2 1
0 1 0
```

so i would like to check if the number above 2 is 0, and to change it to two if it's true. Assuming i = 1 and j = 1:

```
string var = "2";
if(tab[i][j] == var && tab[i-1][j] == "0") {
       tab[i-1][j] = "2";
}
```

here is where i get the segment fault, if i change 0 to 1 in if statement, it works fine. Why? tryied even to make the 2d array as int, same problem.

changing "0" to '0' or vice-versa = same problem.

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    vector<string> current_row;
    for(int j =0; j < m; j++) {
        myfile >> buff;
        current_row.push_back(buff);
    }
    tab.push_back(current_row);

}
```

that's how i populate it.

Comment: How do you declare `tab`?

Comment: std::vector<std::vector<string>> tab;

Comment: I think you should show the portion of the code that actually populates `tab`

Comment: How do you fill it? An [sscce](http://sscce.org) would be helpful.

Comment: i've edited the post, take a loook.

Comment: It looks like the problem is still in the code you're not showing us. Could you post a small, complete program that demonstrates the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you are accessing memory outside of the bounds of the array. One thing that could cause that is if tab[0][?] == var. this causes your condition to check tab[-1][?] and generates an exception.